# build a string that excludes text containing two specific words

Tags: regex, tasker

I am trying to find the inverse of the following string but with no success:

```
(?i)(?s)^(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?word2)
```

I built this but it is for one word only and it does not even function properly, considering that if I test it with regex101 I got one match while I should get no match:

```
(?i)(?s)(?!.*?word2)^.*$
```

Please see the following link:  https://regex101.com/r/qS7yN9/72

Hope you guys can help to build the right string.

Comment: Which programming language or library are you using?

Comment: Your pattern is correct, remove the default m modifier in regex101 that matches `^` as the start of a line. You can also replace `^` with `\A` to be sure to match the start of the string whatever the modifier.

Comment: @melpomene PCRE (PHP) according to regex101...

Comment: @casimir please check if the string modified as follows is what you meant: https://regex101.com/r/qS7yN9/75 if so, please note that with the string modified like this, it searches for the "word1" only, ignoring the words that contain "word1". I would like words like for instance word12345 to be taken into consideration. Moreover, just in case my original post was not clear, the string should exclude text containing two words and only if both are present. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "according to regex101"? Do you just want to make colorful patterns appear on some website, or are you trying to solve a programming problem?

Comment: @melpomene I need to insert that regex string inside Tasker, that is an Android app...so I would say the second one you said

Comment: Tasker [does not use PCRE](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/matching.html#regex) (or PHP, for that matter). It uses [Java regexes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: You may use `(?is)^(?!.*?(?:word1|word2)).*`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/45Htdi/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively negate the result by wrapping a negative look-ahead assertion around the whole thing:

```
(?i)(?s)^(?!(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?word2))
```

Comment: I tested it on regex101 but even both words are contained into the text it still get matches... please give a look here: https://regex101.com/r/qS7yN9/76